# Shortcut for last change on Toad

Tags: shortcut, toad

In some IDE using a shortcut (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> for instance) is possible return to the last changed line.

Is there anything similar in Toad?

I'm writing a very long Stored Procedure and this option could be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toad does not have this, but it does have bookmarks. You can set a numbered bookmark (0-9) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+[0..9]. You can return to a bookmark by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+[0..9].

EDIT: I am assuming you mean Toad for Oracle. I am not familiar with other flavors of Toad if that's what you are inquiring about.

Comment: Yes, I meant Toad for Oracle. I think with bookmark could be good but surely not the same.

Comment: That's all you have to use for this. There is no shortcut to jump to the last modified line.